# How can i install anaconda on Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, python

I need help to install the anaconda python distribution on Ubuntu 14.04. I ran in terminal the bash script `Anaconda.sh`, but I thing I have to do something else after that.

Answer (score 1):

To install [the Anaconda python distribution](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) after obtaining it, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below from the directory containing the script:

```
bash Anaconda-2.0.1-Linux-x86.sh
chmod +x Anaconda-2.0.1-Linux-x86.sh
./Anaconda-2.0.1-Linux-x86.sh
```

Use Anaconda-2.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh for the 64bit file.